# Store the_content() into a javascript/jquery variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

How can I do that ? Store the_content() into a variable . What I've tried :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.the_content = "<?php the_content(); ?>";
</script>
```

and this

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_clean();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.the_content = "<?php echo $content; ?>";
</script>
```

The problem is that what's echo-ed it's a multi-line string and that can't be stored as a javascript variable. I tried to trim() chop() htmlentities_decode() the string but it's useless.

I know that there's a function `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>`that take off the html tags but the spaces and line-breaks are still there. I want to be able to parse the_content() via jquery .

Copy paste of the output from Google Chrome Developer Tool :

```
                                window.the_content = "<h1>Welcome to dasqwe tsqwe dwemo site</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>asdioquwidqwd</p>
<p>qwdoqwkdpqkwdkoqpwodkqwodpqwd</p>
<p>qwdkpoqwkdpqwokdpqwokdpqwkdpqwodkq</p>
<p>wdqwodkqpowkdpqwkdpqwkdopqwkdoq</p>
<p>wdqkowpdkqwpokdpoqkwdpqowkdpoqwkdqwd</p>
<p><span id="more-13"></span></p>
<h1>Page 2</h1>
<p>qwiodjiqwjdqiowjdioqwjdiqwd</p>
<p>qwdjoqwijdoqiwjdioqwjiodjqwodjqowdijas</p>
<p>dqoijwdioqjwdoqjwiodjqwodjqwdjasdqwodijqowdjqiowjdoqjdoad</p>
<p>qwodiqwjdoiqwdijoqwdqwiqiodijoqwdjiqwq</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `json_encode`, it should escape most of the characters that would make it break

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $data = ob_get_contents();        
    ob_end_clean();        
?>
window.the_content = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

You could also just strip out the new lines

```
window.the_content = "<?php str_replace("\n","",the_content()); ?>";
```

Note that you would have to do other stuff to make sure it doesnt break, for instance escape double quotes etc.

Comment: I tried those things but didn't work . In the first example what happen is that at the end of the normal output of the_content() I have a "null" there, and the second example doesn't work I think that's because of "\n" who should be '\n' I changed that but it didn't work too.

Comment: aw thats because the_content doesn't actually return content you would have to do the ob_start() thing that sergiy uses in his answer and then do the encode on the variable

Answer (score 0):

Please replace all the linebreaks to `<br/>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.the_content = "<?php 
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    echo str_replace("\n","<br/>", str_replace("\r", "", $content));              
  ?>
</script>
```

And on the JS-side:

```
$( '.content' ).the_content);
```

Comment: Ok, I changed base64_ to serialize/unserialize. How about that?

Answer (score 0):

JSON Encoding on the PHP side and decoding on the Javascript side will handle this for you.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_clean();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.the_content = <?php echo json_encode($content); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: you don't need the JSON.parse, and actually that will cause an error as it wont be an actual json string. And `the_content()` doesn't actually return anything you would need to capture the content using output buffering first